# How to get data from .net web services via kSOAP 2

Tags: .net, android, ksoap2

I am using kSoap2 to get data from WS. But i get the string "Error" as my out put instead of value "89.6".

can any one tell me where i am going wrong in the following code?

```
package net.manoj.MytestServices;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Main extends Activity { 
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.tempuri.org/";
// private static final String URL = "http://216.128.29.26/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"; 
   TextView tv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope SoapEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    SoapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
    SoapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    HttpTransportSE abt = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    abt.debug = true;

    try {
        abt.call(SOAP_ACTION, SoapEnvelop);
        //SoapPrimitive resultstring = (SoapPrimitive) SoapEnvelop.getResponse();
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) SoapEnvelop.getResponse();
        Object f = result.toString();
        tv.setText("States : " + f);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
    }
```

i am not getting any exception of this. can any one pls help me on this?

Comment: Hi, No one have the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

have u added KSOAP2 jar file.

download this file and add it yopur project.

ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Let me know in case of any errors after that.

Answer (score 0):

Download KSOAP2 jar file from the following link:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Add the downloaded jar file in libs folder in your project.